# Why the [] operator in sorted_vector_map?

Tags: c++, folly

I do not understand what the operator [] does in sorted_vector_map.

- Specifically when the key does not exist, what value is added to the data structure?
- What is `value_type(key, mapped_type())`?
- Is it a constructor call to `std::pair` by default?
- What is `mapped_type()`?
- Is it also a constructor call?

```
mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& key) {
    iterator it = lower_bound(key);
    if (it == end() || key_comp()(key, it->first)) {
      return insert(it, value_type(key, mapped_type()))->second;
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Code is from the following link...

https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/sorted_vector_types.h#L1097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Container` is the template argument that defines what container is used by `sorted_vector_map` to store the key-value pairs and defaults to a `std::vector`(`std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>, Allocator>>`)

`value_type` is `Container::value_type` (`typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;`) which (for the default template argument) is `std::pair<Key, Value>` (see [std::vector Member types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types))

`mapped_type` is `Value` (`typedef Value mapped_type;`) so the type of the value stored in the `sorted_vector_map`

> What is value_type(key, mapped_type())?
> What is mapped_type()?
> Is it also a constructor call?

So `value_type(key, mapped_type())` creates a `std::pair` with `key` as `first`, and a default constructed `Value` (`mapped_type()`) as `second`.

> Is it a constructor call to std::pair by default?

yes

```
template <
    class Key,
    class Value, // <<===============
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<Key, Value>>,
    class GrowthPolicy = void,
    class Container = std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>, Allocator>>   // <<===============
class sorted_vector_map : detail::growth_policy_wrapper<GrowthPolicy> {
  detail::growth_policy_wrapper<GrowthPolicy>& get_growth_policy() {
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename K, typename V, typename C = Compare>
  using if_is_transparent =
      _t<detail::sorted_vector_enable_if_is_transparent<void, C, K, V>>;

  struct EBO;

 public:
  typedef Key key_type;
  typedef Value mapped_type; // <<===============
  typedef typename Container::value_type value_type; // <<===============
  typedef Compare key_compare;
  typedef Allocator allocator_type;
  typedef Container container_type;
```

Comment: If i had a sorted_vector_container object called sv and I were to create an object of type mapped_type, can I do sv:: mapped_type() to invoke the constructor?

Comment: @user1559897 don't ask new questions in the comment. If you have a new question create a new one. You have to use either `decltype` to get the type of `sv`  (`decltype(test)::mapped_type`)  or use `sorted_vector_container<Key,Value>::mapped_type` with `Key` and `Value` being the types you used.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are in the header file.

Consider:

`value_type(key, mapped_type())`

One line 743 of the file you linked, you'll see this declaration:

`typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;`

But what's `Container`?  On line 728 you'll find that Container is a template argument, which is probably a `std::pair` (unless the user has supplied another one).

`class Container = std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>, Allocator>>`

So yes, that line is a constructor call to initialize a `std::pair`, because that's what this particular data structure uses as its value.

`mapped_type()` is also a constructor call, with no arguments.  It's similar to:

`int i = int();`

Comment: I get that Container is std::pair, but why is container::value_type also std::pair? Is this by design?

Comment: No `Container` is not `std::pair` it is - as you wrote - `std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>, Allocator>>` (`std::vector`).